# How to export a StoryBoard for localization

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I have the following storyboard:
[image: TabFiles.storyboard]

With the following localization settings:
[image: TabFiles.storyboard Localization settings]

And my project has the following localizations:
[image: My project's localizations]

If I select Export for Localization by clicking my project, then `Editor > Export for Localization`
Then the `*.xliff` files  correctly have entries for the `TabFiles.storyboard`

If I then add a localization to the `TabFiles.storyboard` file:
[image: TabFiles.storyboard localization settings after adding a language]
and export by selecting my project, then `Editor > Export for Localization`

then my `*.xliff` files no longer have the `TabFiles.storyboard` localizations included in them.

This has been a problem for my localization efforts as the people doing my translations aren't able to make edits after I import their translations from the first time.

Is this expected behaviour? If not, how can I fix this so that my exported xliffs contain all of the translation strings that were there before I added localizations

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of messing around with my storyboard configurations and locations I gave up and tried resetting them in the following way.

Let `$SB` be a storyboard that is showing this weird behaviour

1. `mv $SB ${Path to Base.lproj/}`
2. Find $SB in the project navigator, remove it
3. In the group where `$SB` was removed
4. right click > Add Files to "..."
5. Select `$SB` from `${Path to Base.lproj/}`
6. Add back your localizations.

For some reason, after performing those steps, Export for Localization worked fine.